# Integral with Exponential and Algebraic function, need analytical solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function, normal-distribution

Can anyone help me with following Integral? Mathematica may help, I don't have a Mathematica Licence.

\begin{equation}
\int_{a^2}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} ~e^\frac{-a^2}{x}}{x^3 \sqrt{x-a^2}} ~dx
\end{equation}

where $a$ is a real number.

Comment: @Moo I don't know how to work with those.

Comment: Say, where did this integral come from anyway? A little bit of context always helps.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 well long story, I am trying to find a closed-form for Bayesian Cramer - Rao Bound of an distributed estimation problem, where my noisy observations of unknown are quantized. I came up with a huge integral with Standard Normal PDFs and CDFs, then I used a Chernov Bound to approximate the CDFs and after simplifications I came up with current version.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha, online, is your friend.

Comment: Or Octave. If you cannot download it, you dont deserve the answer.

Comment: A closed form looks to be hard to get.